# Change each symbol excluding variables in bash using sed & regex

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, escaping

I need to change string like

`Example \%^ $variable ${array[$element]}`

Into string like

`\E\x\a\m\p\l\e\ \\\%\^\ $variable\ ${array[$element]}`

So, I need to escape EACH symbol except for variables in those 2 cases.

Also, and this is tricky, I need to escape them twice, so that the result will be achieved by using command:

`` string='Example \%^ $variable ${array[$element]}'
echo `echo $string | sed 'MAGIC' ``

Also, I have achieved escaping ALL the characters:

`echo $(echo $string | sed -r -e 's/(.)/\\\\\1/g')`

So, the question is how to NOT escape $variables?

I am pretty good at regex, so just working example will suffice. But any explanations are welcome. Also, I'll post the answer here if I'd find it faster than any of you. I think it's an interesting puzzle to solve :)

Comment: Please, point out where you read that?

Comment: @Braiam I don't remember, it was a long time ago.

Comment: @EwanCoder If you find the answer to your own question and no-one else offered a suitable answer, it is good to post it as an *answer*. Questions themselves shouldn't be edited to include the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use `perl` then it can be done easily like this:

```
s='Example \%^ $variable"abc" ${array[$element]} ${var}this'
perl -pe 's/\$(?:{.*?}|\w+)(*SKIP)(*F)|(.)/\\$1/g' <<< "$s"
```

**Output:**

```
\E\x\a\m\p\l\e\ \\\%\^\ $variable\"\a\b\c\"\ ${array[$element]}\ ${var}\t\h\i\s
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sM7xT0/2)

---

**Update:** Here is how this can be done using gnu-awk:

```
awk -v RS='\\$({.*?}|[[:alnum:]_]+)' '{gsub(/./, "\\\\&"); printf "%s%s", $0, RT}' <<< "$s"
\E\x\a\m\p\l\e\ \\\%\^\ $variable\"\a\b\c\"\ ${array[$element]} ${var}\t\h\i\s\
```

Comment: Well, I am writing arch linux automagic installation script which works out of box right from live-cd, so I'd better write in pure bash/sed/awk.

But hey, why not use perl?) Even if arch live-cd doesn't include perl out of box, I could just check and install it automatically if it is not present.

Didn't even thought of perl before...

Comment: Oh, I just checked that almost any core piece of software (rxvt, rsync, vim-runtime, git, automake) requires perl as a dependency, so it would probably be installed anyway.

Comment: script does not match double quotes (") after variable, like `$var"` does not become `$var\"`, but becomes `$var"`. In fact, it doesn't catch ANYTHING except for space after variable (like `${var}this`)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/yY1yU7/1 and awk still doesn't match `${var[$i]}THIS`, although I think I can avoid using this in my scripts.

Comment: great, thx, I'll better use perl solution then because awk creates backslash at the end of result, which is critical because that will escape another enclosed quote around whole thing :)